# How can i get a hash into an array, state and acronym?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, state, helper, acronym

```
Array = [{:acronym => "AC", :fullname => "Acre"}, {:acronym => "AL", :fullname => "Alagoas"}, {:acronym => "AP", :fullname => "Amapá"}, {:acronym => "AM", :fullname => "Amazonas"}, {:acronym => "BA", :fullname => "Bahia"}, {:acronym => "CE", :fullname => "Ceará"}, {:acronym => "DF", :fullname => "Distrito Federal"}, {:acronym => "ES", :fullname => "Espírito Santo"}, {:acronym => "GO", :fullname => "Goiás"}, {:acronym => "MA", :fullname => "Maranhão"}, {:acronym => "MT", :fullname => "Mato Grosso"}, {:acronym => "MS", :fullname => "Mato Grosso do Sul"}, {:acronym => "MG", :fullname => "Minas Gerais"}, {:acronym => "PA", :fullname => "Pará"}, {:acronym => "PB", :fullname => "Paraíba"}, {:acronym => "PR", :fullname => "Paraná"}, {:acronym => "PE", :fullname => "Pernambuco"}, {:acronym => "PI", :fullname => "Piauí"}, {:acronym => "RR", :fullname => "Roraima"}, {:acronym => "RO", :fullname => "Rondônia"}, {:acronym => "RJ", :fullname => "Rio de Janeiro"}, {:acronym => "RN", :fullname => "Rio Grande do Norte"}, {:acronym => "RS", :fullname => "Rio Grande do Sul"}, {:acronym => "SC", :fullname => "Santa Catarina"}, {:acronym => "SP", :fullname => "São Paulo"}, {:acronym => "SE", :fullname => "Sergipe"}, {:acronym => "TO", :fullname => "Tocantins"}]
```

How can I compare a variable with `:acronym` and return the `:fullname` in other variable?
I'm trying to do this using a Rails helper.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you don't want to call your array `Array` as that's a class name and it is already taken.

You could do this:

```
def find_acronym_in(array, acronym)
    # returns nil if we don't find a match.
    array.find { |h| h[:acronym] == acronym }.try(:fetch, :fullname)
end
```

and in your ERB:

```
<%= find_acronym_in(@acronyms, 'ES') %>
```

That's a simple linear search so it will be slow for large lists but it probably won't be noticeable for short lists.

If you're doing a lot of this or if you have large lists then you could rearrange your array into a simple Hash in your controller:

```
@acronyms_hash = @acronyms.each_with_object({ }) { |h, memo| memo[h[:acronym]] = h[:fullname] }
```

and then just pull things out of the Hash as needed:

```
<%= @acronyms_hash['ES'] %>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do it

```
acronym_to_find = "SE"
Array.select { |ac| ac[:acronym] == acronym_to_find }.first[:fullname]
```

Your data would probably be better structured as a hash of { acronym => fullname} pairs, though.